# More Database Freedom From GORM/Grails

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm new to Grails/Groovy and practicing rebuilding a simple app that I built in another language. I modeled my domain classes based on the existing database from the app.

I first tried to reverse engineer with the plugin but ran into issues with various errors and decided to recreate the app from scratch for practice.

One of the tables has a self-reference, parent/child relationship. When I set that up in the domain class based on examples that I seen online, everything appeared to be fine. I noticed that GORM created a FK and was enforcing relational integrity.

I tried importing the data into the generated table which was causing errors related to the FK and not being allowed to import due to that relationship.

One option was to add an int column for the parent_id and handle it manually like I was doing in the previous version, but I was hoping that there was a work around for this without having to do that.

Comment: So the issue is how can you import that data without violating the FK?

Comment: In case you are trying to import your data by a number of insert statements you can simply disable the foreign key, import the data and enable the foreign key again.

Comment: I ended up looking at the lecture from Burt Beckwith on "no more gorm/collections..." and see how it was handled there so that performance would be improved.